# css for phonegap-How do I make three list items share the page equally?

Tags: html, css, cordova

I am trying to make a PhoneGap app and the main menu has the title and three buttons, like this:

```
  <body>
        <div class="app">
            <div class="headerOne">
                <h1></h1>
            </div>  
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a class="shop">Shop</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="login">Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="account">New Account</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </body>
```

I want these buttons to fill the page but be able to change for different phone screens how do I do this? Here's my CSS:

```
<!-- language:lang-css -->
* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); /* make transparent link selection, adjust last value opacity 0 to 1.0 */
}

body {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;                
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;             
    -webkit-user-select: none;                  
    background-color:#E4E4E4;

    background-image:linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);

    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        left bottom,
        color-stop(0, #A7A7A7),
        color-stop(0.51, #E4E4E4)
    );

    background-attachment:fixed;
    font-family:'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'HelveticaNeue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    width:100%;
}

/* Portrait layout (default) */
.app {
    height:100%;                   /* text area height */
    width:100%;                   /* text area width */
    text-align:center;  
}

/* Landscape layout (with min-width) */
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
    .app {
        background-position:left center;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    }
}

.headerOne{
border: 1px solid black;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #333333);
width:100%;
height:30px;
border-radius: 2px;
font-size:24px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-align:center;
color:white;
margin-bottom:30px;
}

.menu li{
margin-top:30px;
min-height:30px;
min-width:60px; 
}

.shop{
border:1px solid black;
border-radius:2px;
background:black;
color:white;
-webkit-box-shadow:rgb(110,110,110) 2px 2px;
}

.login{
border:1px solid black;
border-radius:2px;
background:black;
color:white;
-webkit-box-shadow:rgb(110,110,110) 2px 2px;
-webkit-box-flex:1;
}

.account{
border:1px solid black;
border-radius:2px;
background:black;
color:white;
-webkit-box-shadow:rgb(110,110,110) 2px 2px;
-webkit-box-flex:1;
}

@keyframes fade {
    from { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.4; }
    to { opacity: 1.0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.4; }
    to { opacity: 1.0; }
}
```

i also have a standard format css file, thought i would would put it on to see if its affecting it:

```
 html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
    del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
    small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
    b, u, i, center,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
    fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
    article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
    figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
    menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
    time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
    footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
    }
    body {
    line-height: 1;
    }
    ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
    }
    blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
    }
    blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
    q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
    }
    table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried

```
height: 33.3%
```

for each item ?

PS. If they will not fit the layout, use `height: 100%` on html and body

PPS. Use absolute layout. eg. headerOne `top:0; left: 0; right: 0; height: 30px` , and menu `top: 30px; left:0; right: 0; bottom: 0;`

Comment: Other way is to use completely absolute layout. I didn't walk thru your css, but this works fine in my apps

Comment: Also every parent element must have height set or position absolute

Comment: also i used a format css file to set the page so it is a blank slate this might be affecting it